# is there any way to update props on some different component which is not child component or parent component on custom dispatch event?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

i am learning svelte i don't wan to use any store management etc. i am trying to grab the basics of svelte in depth i have tried alot but i dont see any fix for this ,
this is my code

```
<script>
    const toggleModal = () => {
        openModal = !openModal
    }
    const addPersonCustomEvent = (e) => {
        person = e.detail;
        console.log(person)
        // PersonsLoop.set({personData: person})
    }
</script>

<main>
    <Header />
    <button on:click={() => {toggleModal()}}>open modal</button>
    <section>
        <PersonsLoop personData={person} />
    </section>
</main>
<Modal isPromo={true} body="main modal here" openModal={openModal} on:click={() => {toggleModal()}}  >
    <Form on:addPerson={addPersonCustomEvent} />
</Modal>
```

in this i have created a addPerson custom event and forwarding that event to the  component , currently it is setting the value in person variable but it is not updating the value in  PersonsLoop component
i am logging the value in personsloop component and it is not working is there anyway to do that

> **Update** i think basically what i want to ask is how to rerender component when prop updates

Comment: This code should work, there must be something else going on, you can try reproducing it on: http://www.svelte.dev/repl (start with the minimum like one form component and one render component and add more complexity)

Comment: Just a thought: can you add `PersonsLoop` as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the variable `person`. You're always passing into `PersonLoop` an `undefined` value. That's why your changes doesn't reflect into `personData`.

Add this line in your code and should be fine:

```
<script>
    let person;
    // the rest seems fine ...
</script>
```

Check this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/feae2bbb6b1049ea896425f90d683349?version=3.46.4) if you want a minimal working example

Comment: no sir i am trying to pass the updated props in personloop but in the personloop it is not updating the values thats the issue

Comment: Ok, so you should update your post and include "PersonsLoop" code otherwise we can't fully understand where the problem is.